# Code formatting with XHtmlTextWriter and Control instance

Tags: c#, xhtml, htmltextwriter

`XHtmlTextWriter` takes second parameter `tabString`. I set it to `HtmlTextWriter.DefaultTabString`

When we use `xhtmlTextWriter.WriteLine()`, it indents the code.

But if we use `control.RenderControl(xhtmlTextWriter)`, it performs only one indentation for the root element.

```
public string Rendering(Control baseControl)
{

    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (XhtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new XhtmlTextWriter(stringWriter,
                                                     HtmlTextWriter.DefaultTabString))
    {
        baseControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

It seems like `Control.RenderControl()` is recursively aggregating child nodes in a temporary string and then with a single `WriteLine()`, its writing to `XHtmlTextWriter`.

Ideally, its suppose to call `WriteLine()` for each node, to respect `HtmlTextWriter`'s second parameter.

Due to this glitch, after rendering (un-indented) markup to string, I need to pass the string to `XPathDocument`, and create `XPathNavigator` then convert back to string, which does the desired formatting.

```
public string Rendering(Control baseControl)
{
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (XhtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new XhtmlTextWriter(stringWriter,
                                                     HtmlTextWriter.DefaultTabString))
    {
        baseControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

        return UnwantedFormatting(stringWriter.ToString());
    }
}

private string UnwantedFormatting(string markup)
{
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(markup);
    XPathDocument doc;
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr,
                       new XmlReaderSettings()
                       {
                           ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
                           // for multiple roots
                        }))
    {
        doc = new XPathDocument(xr);
    }

    return doc.CreateNavigator().InnerXml.ToString();
}
```

Is there a better way to render control to string with indentation without this undesired *extra* formatting step?